# node.jsとmysqlで複数のqueryを実行したい

Tags: mysql, node.js

この前から色々検索しながらnode.jsとjavascriptを使用してサイトを作ろうとしています。
複数のクエリの結果をejsに送るというコードを書こうとしているのですが、エラーになってしまいます。
res.renderの前でresults[0].length、results[1].length、results[2].lengthをすると正しいサイズが表示されるので、多分取得は出来ていると思います。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974598/unexpected-token-return-in-while-compiling-ejs
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Malformed_formal_parameter
上記の質問などがヒットしましたが、includeは使っていません。
ejs-lintも使用してみました。

```
/home/ubuntu/views/results.ejs
  1:1  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token <

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

しかし、1行目の1文字目の<はhtmlタグなので、そこでエラーが出るとは考えにくいです。
初歩的な質問で申し訳ございません。皆様の知恵をお借りしたいです。
よろしくお願い致します。

```
//server.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

let http = require('http');
let fs = require('fs');
let mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  multipleStatements:true,
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'ユーザー名',
  password: 'パスワード',
  database: 'データベース名'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Connected');
});

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index.ejs');
  
});

app.post("/result", (req, res) => {
  let selected = req.body.selected_series;
  let series;
  let human_series, item_series, quotation_series;
  //クエリを変数に入れる
  if(selected === "one"){
    series = "SELECT * FROM human where series = " + 1 + "; SELECT * FROM item WHERE series = " + 1 + ";"; 
  }else if(selected === "two"){
    series = "SELECT * FROM human where series = " + 2 + "; SELECT * FROM item WHERE series = " + 2 + "; SELECT * FROM quotation WHERE series" + ";";
    
  }else if(selected === "nt"){
    series = "SELECT * FROM human where series = " + 3 + "; SELECT * FROM item WHERE series = " + 3 + "; SELECT * FROM  quotation series = " + 3 + ";";
  }else{
    human_series = Math.floor( Math.random() * 4 );
    item_series = Math.floor( Math.random() * 4 );
    quotation_series = Math.floor( Math.random() * 4 );
    series = "SELECT * FROM human where series = " + human_series + "; SELECT * from item where series = " + item_series + "; SELECT * from quotation where series = " + quotation_series +";";
  }
  connection.query(
    series,
      (error, results) => {
      res.render('results.ejs', {humans: results[0], items:results[1], quotations: results[2]});
      } 
    );
  });


app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("My app listening on port 3000!");
});
```

表示するためのreults.ejs

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>結果</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <% Object.values(humans); %>
    <% Object.values(items); %>
    <% Object.values(quotations); %>
    <p>-----登場人物-----</p>
    <% humans.forEach(human) => { %>
      <%= human %>
    <% } %>
    <p>-----アイテム-----</p>
    <% items.forEach(item) => { %>
      <%= item %>
    <% } %>
    <p>-----一言-----</p>
    <% quotations.forEach(quotation) => { %>
      <%= quotation %>
    <% } %>
    <a href="/">もう一度占う</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

エラー内容

```
SyntaxError: Malformed arrow function parameter list in /home/ubuntu/views/results.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at Template.compile (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:662:12)
    at Object.compile (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:396:16)
    at handleCache (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:233:18)
    at tryHandleCache (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:272:16)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:489:10)
    at View.render (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
```

追記
server.jsに値を渡しているので一応index.ejsも貼ります。

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="siren.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <title>たいとる</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>シリーズを選択してください</p>
    <form action="/result" method="POST">
      <select id="select_series" name="selected_series">
        <option value="none" name="series">--選択してください--</option>
        <option value="one" name="series">SIREN</option>
        <option value="two" name="series">SIREN2</option>
        <option value="nt" name="series">SIREN:NT</option>
        <option value="all" name="series">全シリーズ</option>
      </select>
      <button type="submit" id="select">決定</button>
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) の "JavaScript Demo: Array.forEach()" にある書き方と `results.ejs` の `forEach` の書き方を比べて見て下さい。

Answer (score 1):

ありがとうございます。
forEachの書き方が違うという初歩的なミスでした。

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>結果</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <% Object.values(humans); %>
    <% Object.values(items); %>
    <% Object.values(quotations); %>
    <p>-----登場人物-----</p>
    <% humans.forEach(human => { %>
      <%= human %>
    <% }); %>
    <p>-----アイテム-----</p>
    <% items.forEach(item => { %>
      <%= item %>
    <% }); %>
    <p>-----一言-----</p>
    <% quotations.forEach(quotation => { %>
      <%= quotation %>
    <% }); %>
    <a href="/">もう一度占う</a>
  </body>
</html>
```